# Is there any Lua library that converts a string to bytes using UTF8 encoding?

Tags: lua

I wonder whether this kind of library exists.

Comment: UTF8 is already bytes. Do you want it converted to something else?

Answer (score 5):

[slnunicode](http://luaforge.net/projects/sln/) is part of the collection of general purpose lua support libraries developed for the Selene database project.

It's also available as a [luarock](http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/#slnunicode)

Comment: unfortunately doesn't compile on lua v5.2.0

Answer (score 4):

Lua strings are a sequence of bytes. When you store UTF8 text in them, you're already storing "UTF8 bytes". You can get the bytes like with all other strings, using `string.byte(s,i,j)`:

```
local bytes = { string.byte(unicodeString, 1,-1) }
```

Now bytes is a table containing your "UTF8 bytes".
More information about `string.byte` and UTF8 in Lua is available at:

Standard Lua [string library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4)

Lua 5.3 standard [utf8 library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5)

[Presentation by Roberto Ierusalimschy (one of the creators of Lua)](http://www.lua.org/wshop12/Ierusalimschy.pdf) on the future of Lua, which talks about many things and one of them is UTF8 support. It was released before UTF8 support was built into Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Lua 5.3 has [UTF-8 support](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5) in the standard library now.

For example, to get a UTF-8 string's code points:

```
for p, c in utf8.codes("瑞&于") do
  print(c)
end
```

Output:

```
29790
38
20110
```