# Splitting a multibyte string in Lua

Tags: string, utf-8, lua, coronasdk, multibyte

I have a multibyte string in Lua.

```
local s = "あいうえお"
```

How do I take the string and split it into a table of strings?

In English texts, then I can use this code. But this does not work with the multibyte.

```
local s = "foo bar 123"
local words = {}
for word in s:gmatch("%w+") do
    table.insert( words, word )
end
```

Comment: Where are the boundaries between "words" in Japanese? Or do you simply need to split that string into a table of individual characters, like this? {"あ", "い", "う", "え", "お"}

Comment: Use [ICU4Lua](https://github.com/duncanc/icu4lua/)

Comment: ICU is also an enormous heavyweight library, and is completely unnecessary for simple UTF-8 processing in Lua (using ICU for many tasks is probably much slower to boot, because you pay the price of converting your strings to/from its internal format rather than operating on them directly).

Answer (score 7):

As others have noted, it's hard to tell what you want to do:  *where* do you want to split for non-ASCII characters, if splitting at spaces doesn't suffice?

If you just want to split between individual characters for non-ASCII characters, something like the following may suffice:

```
s = "oink barf 頑張っています"
for word in s:gmatch("[\33-\127\192-\255]+[\128-\191]*") do
   print (word)
end
```

produces:

```
oink
barf
頑
張
っ
て
い
ま
す
```

The trick here is that in UTF-8, multi-byte characters each consist of a "lead byte" with the top two bits equal to `11` (so `\192`–`\255` in Lua—remember, character escapes in Lua are decimal), followed by zero or more "trailing bytes" with the top two bits equal to `10` (`\128`–`\191` in Lua).

Answer (score 4):

For a start .. from this SO question [How to write a unicode symbol in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983574/how-to-write-a-unicode-symbol-in-lua), RBerteig's answer points to a library [slnunicode](https://github.com/LuaDist/slnunicode)

Also referred to in this SO question [Is there any lua library that converts a string to bytes using utf8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876910/is-there-any-lua-library-that-converts-a-string-to-bytes-using-utf8-encoding)

Comment: Extensive Unicode libraries are a possible solution, but often _very_ heavyweight.  It's not really clear what the question author really wants to split on here, so it's a little hard to tell what exactly the best method is, but for many simple utf-8 tasks, it's quite reasonable to just write methods directly operating on the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

If it's UTF-8, In Lua 5.3, you can use the [`utf8` library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5) like this:

```
local s = "あいうえお"
local words = {}
for _, c in utf8.codes(s) do
  table.insert(words, utf8.char(c))
end
```